# Is this storing method sql injection "safe"?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have just finished writing my own php registration script from scratch and since I am new to this I wanted to ask if the method I'm using is safe from sql injections?

This is an example how I exchange data with my sql database:

```
public function StoreUser($name, $email, $password, $devid) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "data");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $unique_id = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);

    $add_user = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` SET `unique_id`=?, `name`=?, `email`=?, `encrypted_password`=?, `salt`=?, `devid`=?, `created_at`=?");
    $add_user->bind_param("sssssss",$unique_id,$name,$email,$hash["encrypted"],$hash["salt"],$devid,date("H:i:s"));
    if ($add_user->execute()) {
        $add_user->close();
        $mysqli->close();
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        $add_user->close();
        $mysqli->close();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [proper SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is an important first step towards making your application secure. In this case you shouldn't have to worry about any SQL injection bugs, the escaping should be done for you if you're disciplined about using placeholders for *any* and *all* user-supplied data, but there could be other issues.

Remember that just as you escape things for a SQL statement, you should likewise be diligent about escaping user-supplied data before displaying it as HTML or you could end up with all kinds of issues, the worst of which is [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

In any case, [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) makes it a lot easier to do the escaping. `mysqli` is usually used only if PDO is not available.

There is no singular magic bullet, but there are a number of things you can do to prevent your application from being abused, or just suffering embarrassing bugs. This can be difficult to do if you're writing your own low-level database interfacing code instead of using a framework, though. You'll spend a lot of time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: thanks for your tips! I will look into that.

The problem is that I haven't found any appropriate frameworks for my project. I need a database to create a list of user for an android app. And i haven't found any satisfying framework yet.

Comment: The more popular PHP choices are [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com) all of which are significantly better than starting from scratch. These aren't too tricky to learn, but you'll have to deal with doing things the way the framework expects them, applying convention, or they might feel difficult. There's usually a reason for these conventions, though, and as you better understand the philosophy, a lot of things you do become significantly easier to implement. You should be implementing your business logic, not boilerplate.

Comment: Once you pick a framework, too, you'll have access to all kinds of [pre-made things](http://plugins.cakephp.org/). Going it alone is like trying to hike through the wilderness. It can be educational, but if your goal is to get somewhere instead of explore, then you should be using a road if there's one going to where you want to be.

Comment: Please, please don't suggest CakePHP, CodeIgniter or FuelPHP. Those are among the three worst PHP frameworks and are far, far worse than starting from scratch. @user1880863 if you must use a framework, look into Symfony -- but don't use it's base controller class as it forces you into using the service locator antipattern.

Comment: If your alternative has such a glaring flaw in your opinion, is it really better? In any case, there are [options](http://www.phpzag.com/top-5-php-frameworks-2012/). Those three frameworks I mentioned do get attention on Stack Overflow, so at least they're supported. Would [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) be a better suggestion?

Comment: I would also argue that there is nothing wrong with starting from scratch.  Frameworks are tools, and there are appropriate times to use them, no doubt.  Those times don't come up on every project.  Also, @tadman, proper escaping needs to be used with all data, not just user-supplied data.  It is incorrect to suggest that escaping data for a database is just for security.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is safe.

You are using parameterized queries which fundamentally separate the data from the command, making you safe from first-order SQL injection attacks.